# Make the player move forward (facing towards its front) in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently working on a game in LibGDX. You may have seen another post. I have solved that problem, but now, I am facing the fact that I can't seem to move my player towards (it always moves up instead of pointing towards its front). I have tried everything, from using Box2D to answers I found online that suggested to use trig functions. Has anyone managed to do this before?

Answer (score 0):

The movement of objects is usualy done by setting their x (left and right) and y (up and down) coordinates.
To know how to manipulate them, you need to know the direction he is faicng.
In a top-down game it could be a `Vector2`, a normalized `Vector` (a `Vector` of length=1), which gives you the relative movement in x and y direction. In a platformer instead it could be only a `boolean`, which defines if you are facing the rigth or the left. The up/down movement is then defined by jumping and other "up-forces" and the gravitation.

I think in your case it is a top-down-game, so you need a `Vector2`.
When you `rotate` your character you need to `rotate` the `Vector2` to. To make sure, your `Vector2` is normalized allways call `nor()` after manipulating it.
In the `update` or `render` method you should the set the x and y coordinates of your character like this:

```
player.x = direction.x*delta*speed;
player.y = direction.y*delta*speed;
```

Where `delta` is the `Gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime()` and `speed` is the movementspeed of your player.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is this "direction" means position of player?

Comment: @furyfish no, the `player.x` and `player.y` is the position, the `direction` is a normalized (length==1) `Vector`,giving the percentage of movement in `x` and `y`, it is where the player is watching. If  you are watching to the left, the `direction.x` is -1, and the `direction.y` is 0. If you are watching rigth up (45°) the `direction.x` is 0.5 and the `direction.y` is also 0.5